# How to make _.each handle both 'array' and 'array of array' in $.when done handler

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, underscore.js

I have to perform a number of json calls and apply callback to the result. The number of call is unknown until runtime. Therefore I use `$.when.apply` to pass an array of promise to `when`.

```
  jsonPromises     = []
  newContentActions = []
  for model in models
      jsonPromises.push contentCreator.create(model)
      action = new ActionHandler model
      newContentActions.push action

  $.when.apply($, jsonPromises)
  .then (args...) =>
    _.each args, (result, idx) =>
      return unless result[1] is 'success'
      action = newContentActions[idx]
      action result[0]
```

It works as expected, more or less. When there is more than 1 promise, the `then` handler of `$.when` will get an array of array (e.g.`[[Object, "success", Object], [Object, "success", Object]]` as seen in Chrome dev console). `_.each` can then correctly unpack it into `result, idx`.

However if there is only 1 promise, I will only get a single array in the `then`handler. It confuses `_.each`. `each` unpacks the single array and results into 3 function calls. And my app fails.

To get around this I make an extra check on the number of promise. When there is only one I will not use `$.when`:

```
  if jsonPromises.length is 1
    jsonPromises[0].done (model) =>
      action = newContentActions[0]
      action model
  else
    $.when.apply($, jsonPromises)
    .then (args...) =>
      _.each args, (result, idx) =>
        return unless result[1] is 'success'
        action = newContentActions[idx]
        action result[0]
```

Is it the only way to achieve this result? Is there a way to remove the 
`jsonPromises.length is 1` check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to just wrap the args in an array if you see that `jsonPromises.length` is 1

```
  $.when.apply($, jsonPromises)
  .then (args...) =>
    args = [args] if jsonPromises.length is 1
    _.each args, (result, idx) =>
    return unless result[1] is 'success'
    action = newContentActions[idx]
    action result[0]
```